# I have a misspelling in a repository source file, and it's lousing up my ability to download

Tags: repository, software-sources, boot-repair

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 11.04, and because of rebooting issues, I was downloading boot-repair using the live CD.  I've been able to get into 11.04, but now I can't do any more upgrades.

Whenever I try to use the Ubuntu Software Center, the Synaptic Package Manager, or even the terminal, the following error message keeps coming up:

```
E:Type 'oot-repair/ubuntu' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-maverick.list'
```

Of course, "oot-repair" is really "boot-repair".  I was able to locate `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` in the root directory and saw it with my own eyes, but I don't know how to repair the misspelling.

What should I do?

Comment: For information, this is due to a bug of add-apt-repository : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/789859

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal and issue this command:

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-maverick.list
  ```
- Then place a `b` in front of `oot-repair` to change it to `boot-repair`.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the file and exit.

You're done. Now you can do, update.

Comment: Should be gksudo and not sudo...

Comment: @arochester, thanks. I've edited. I heard of sudo issue, though it works always good for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried sudo nano, but it wouldn't work.  You know what they say about using a bigger hammer--I simply deleted the file (it was a notification that that particular version of boot repair was being disabled at upgrade), so now I'm back in business.  Thanks anyway.  I'll remember gksudo gedit next time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do  it apart from Anwar Shah's answer is to type in terminal  - `gksudo nautilus`

The file explorer will open up.

Browse to the directory -  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
PS: copy the directory link and in nautilus press ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + 
<kbd>L</kbd> and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Open up the file with any file editor (or just double click it) - `yannubuntu-boot-repair-maverick.list`

And edit the required thing - place a `b` in front of `oot-repair` to change it to `boot-repair.`

Save the document and you are done.